Help With Ubuntu 24.04 LTS!
I Need Your Help With Ubuntu 24.04 LTS! I Worked with Linux for about 4 years and i know how to work with it. It was so good for me and i was comfortable with it; But Ubuntu 24.04 looks so weird! It gets me "No irq handler for vector" error on boot; I can't open app center and install any .deb files; I can't install my graphics card driver; etc.

I Use a PC With gigabyte GA-MA770T-UD3P Motherboard and Nvidia geforce 7100 gs graphics card from 2009. and also, i haven't any libreoffice, any games or any apps; and sometimes when i restart my computer, the system gets me kernel panic in boot screen! it booted up in non-graphical boot screen mode!

Did you upgrade or fresh install?

Why not, instead, install 22.04LTS which is well tested, stable, and most bugs have been ironed out? When you say it ‘looks weird’, what Linux distribution / version are you used to?

yes, i fresh installed it 2 times (the second time because it got me an error about cdrom noble error).

i know that i use the first release of ubuntu 24.04 and it's normal to show me bugs and hasn't any apps. i used 22.04 and 22.10 and 23.10 versions of ubuntu in their first releases and they hadn't any bugs; i also installed them on vmware and virtualbox to test them before installing them on real pc.

As others said, it's best to use 22.04 until the 24.04.1 version releases.

i wait for 24.04.1 release as soon as canonical developers release is; even if it takes about a year!

i checked it before posting this question and i didn't found any options about this in my bios; i updated my bios to the latest release. i have another problem with installing graphics card in my system as it doesn't found my driver's file.

Ubuntu 24.04 is having serious Nvidia issues -- the 545 and 550 drivers are not even offered for my rtx3080, so your older card having problems is not a surprise.  Wait a bit till these errors get sorted (launchpad bug 2037004)

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please take the tour and try to ask a single, clear, answerable question. AskUbuntu is not designed for discussion nor for complaints. "I need your help" is not an answerable question.

Thank you about these comments; but i can't find any option about IOMMU in advanced bios options in my bios.

This happen always after the release of new version despite being a LTS one. what  you should do now is use the previous LTS 22.04 version and wait until canonical launch the corrective version LTS+1.1 (24.04.1)
